# Drupal block revision control for Writer, Editor, and Publisher role users

Tags: drupal-7, revision

Is there any Drupal module to control the block content before being published.

A person will create a block and post content and assign to Editor role user.
The Editor will review the block content and made his changes on the content and assign to reviewer role user.
The reviewer will review the content and publish or unpublish it, untill he publish the block content the page should retain old published content if any.

Please highlight what are modules can I go for it.

Comment: I think this question fits better here: [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/project/block_access

Block Access module may be what you need.